# "Need to install JAI Image I/O package." error when using tess4j in IntelliJ IDEA Scala SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, tesseract, jai, tess4j

The below tess4j JARs are part of my Scala SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA and are also added as module dependencies:

[image]

However, I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Need to install JAI Image I/O package. https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/` exception when trying to run the following code in a Scala worksheet:

```
import java.io.File
import net.sourceforge.tess4j._

val imageFile = new File("LinkToJPGFile")
val instance = new Tesseract()
instance.setDatapath("MyTessdataFolder")

val result = instance.doOCR(imageFile)
print(result)
```

even though `jai-imageio-core-1.3.1.jar` is properly included in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the JARs individually, add the below line to your build.sbt:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.tess4j" % "tess4j" % "3.3.1"
```

Or whichever version you are using found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j